# Indexing pytorch tensors with tensors swaps batch dimension

Tags: indexing, pytorch

I have the following situation

`M_shape=torch.Size([1000,8,2,8,2])` where 1000 is my batch dimension.
`A_shape=torch.Size([2,2])` and `B_shape=torch.Size([1000, 8, 2])`.

I also have a tensor `ts=tensor([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])` to use for indexing.

Now if I do the following:
`M[:, ts+1, :, ts, :] = A[:,:] * B[:, ts, None, :]`

I get a runtime error

```py
RuntimeError: shape mismatch: value tensor of shape [1000, 7, 2, 2] cannot be broadcast to indexing result of shape [7, 1000, 2, 2]
```

because the first two dimensions get swapped in `M[:, ts+1, :, ts, :]`.
Does anyone know how to retain the correct shape of a torch array when indexing with two tensors?